# How to open the motor cover of craftsman electric lawn mower?

Tags: lawn-mower, repair, electric

## Problem

The lawn mower suddenly stopped working during grass cutting

### Lawn mower details

I have an old model of craftsman lawn mower (2013 model?). It says 20" corded 12 Amp electric on the top. I am trying to open its motor cover to find the problem. But I can't find any way to open the cover. There are 2 grooves on either side, and 2 holes at the front (see the images below). I have tried to use different screwdrivers in them to unscrew if there are any screws in there (can't see any). But nothing has worked so far. Please help me opening the motor cover. I can't even find the manual online.

[image]

How can I open the motor cover?  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Johannes_B Lawn mower maintenance is on-topic on this site. Please don't ask people to post questions elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

That model or a similar appearing model has the battery cover/cowl snap/clip on, so maybe try wriggle it a bit, as any debris shouldn't impede removal too much: the grooves may be spring detents, and the holes could have screws down in them, or simply plastic clips. then to put it back on, clip it back into place & check that its held on ok.

Please be certain that its unplugged when working around it or on it, in addition to being switched off! Its very possible that over time vibration has caused a connector to come loose or break, or a wire has broken etc. Also, on cordless models, the batteries are held in with a tiewrap.., but the batteries are probably available, similiar or interchangeable with back up pwr supply types same as for PCs etc, generally four 12v units with connector clips onto the terminals. Please be careful working around it, until the batteries are disconnected, it could spin etc, same for when reconnecting.

If it stopped abruptly, could be a connector around the motor,  or controls, or a broken wire, or possibly the motor itself. eg, over time, vibration could have loosened a connector, worn a wire through, or terminal failure, or connector on the motor, or corrosion.

Also, maybe double check that the pwr cord is connected ok and that pwr is reaching the outlet the pwr cords attached to, & is reaching the mower.